# Frequent eaddrnotavail in httpc

Tags: concurrency, erlang

I randomly receive `EADDRNOTAVAIL` when connecting to a remote CouchDB in a high concurrency processing of events in my erlang process. Since there are many other http connections between my process and nodejs and redis services are on the same local machine, I've increased OS's `local_port_range` and `ERL_MAX_PORTS` but still got that error.
When getting the error, retrying the http request gets OK.

Any other OS or Erlang specific tuning? or what?

Comment: I would check ulimit as every socket connection takes a handle.

Comment: If what Alex Pakka suggested does not help, simply remove away from that machine the service that requires most of the HTTP connections.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'd increased the ulimit! and I think my last effort would be splitting services in separate machines. I don't think 10000 - 100000 connections won't scale in a single machine!

Comment: and I also get some remote_socket_closed errors. with some searches I found [this](http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/confusing-returns-from-httpc-request-4-td2967066.html) that shows these are related to erlang http client implementation so I'm thinking of replacing the built-in httpc with a more robust library.